# PayPal WPP requires the PHP cURL library. (Currently using cURL Not found)

Tags: php, drupal, curl, drupal-6, ubercart

On the Ubercart module, whenever I enable PayPal it gives me this error:

> PayPal WPP requires the PHP cURL library. (Currently using cURL Not 
>   found)

I have no idea...
Can some one please tell me how to handle this problem...

Note:
OS-windows 7,
Drupal version:6

Comment: .... try installing/enabling curl?

Comment: Is that(cURL) library or module?

Comment: run a phpinfo() and this will tell you what modules and extensions are loaded

Answer (score 1):

```
Enter
WampServer on your taskbar
PHP
Php Extentions
enable php_curl

It's work.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable curl in your PHP setting files.

If its a shared hosting, do it by contacting your webservice.

Depending upon what your software is, in Wamp, your do it by clicking on that task icon -> PHP settings -> Curl

Comment: what are you using? wamp? or independent apache/php/mysql?

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem yesterday.
Solution (Worked for me):

1.- Uncomment the following line in `php/php.ini`

```
;extension=php_curl.dll
```

2.- Restart Apache

It's probably the step after TerryE's solution.

Answer (score 0):

PayPal requires an outside connection to the internet for the exchange of data.
WAMP doesn't provide it ( referring to [Ubercart website](http://www.ubercart.org/forum/support/10016/paypal_php_and_curl_wampserver) )

- It works with XAMPP (tested by me, from Wamp exported same files and db to Xampp)
- It should work when you upload to the real site(reported by some users).